# Node.js HTTP Get stream freezes inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, http, http-streaming

I have following code written in nodejs using `http` module.
It's basically listens to event stream (so the connection is permanent).

```
http.get(EVENT_STREAM_ADDRESS, res => {
  res.on('data', (buf) => {
    const str = Buffer.from(buf).toString();
    console.log(str);
  });

  res.on('error', err => console.log("err: ", err));
});
```

If I run the above code on my Mac it works fine and I get *data* logged to console after many hours.
But in the Docker, which has pretty basic configuration it stops receiving data after some time without any error. Other endpoints in the app are working fine (eg. Express endpoints) but this one `http.get listener` is just hanging.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:current-alpine

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 4000

CMD npm install && npm run start
```

Do you have any ideas how I can overcome this?

It's really hard to debug as to reproduce the situation I sometimes need to wait a few hours.

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked the container logs? Maybe the host computer sleeps and pause the Docker containers?

Comment: could be an issue related to timeout / memory, try putting a console log outside res.on

Answer (score 0):

I find out what is probably happening.

The problem is Docker Desktop for Mac. It seems it stops container sometimes like in the situation that you Mac goes to sleep. And it interrupts the listener so it stops receiving new data chunks.
I started same container on Ubuntu in VirtualBox and it works fine all the time.